# How do I capture the state of an object in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have developed a web app in Django to record sales in a retail store.
I have the following two models in my project:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    cost_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

class Sale(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The problem I'm having is that when I edit the price on the product, it will also affect past sales of that product. This is because the product is a foreign key on the sale model.
What is the best method to ensure that all sales are not affected by any edits on the product?

I thought about adding a price field on the sale model to ensure that the price remains static, like so:

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the best solution, it seems hard coded in a way.
I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: I think you need to create another model to save the sale product, for example you can create SaleDetail model that contains sale_id, product_id, quantity, sub_total, etc. and then you can remove product foreignkey from Sale model.